# How to download a Dropbox folder someone shared me?

Tags: dropbox

Someone has shared a Dropbox folder with me. I got a URL to access the folder through the web interface. How can I download the entire folder?

**Note:** The folder is too large to add to my Dropbox.

Answer (score 18):

There's kind of a workaround. Add

```
?dl=1
```

at the end of the link that was shared with you. This will download the entire folder as a neatly zipped archive.

**Note:** [This will not work with folders > 20GB or with more than 10,000 files](http://dropbox.com/en/help/49).

Comment: This doesn't work for me -- it must have changed since then.

Comment: This worked for me!

Comment: @JoLiss I just checked, and it still seems to work just fine.

Comment: It is not working anymore.

Comment: It is working, it downloaded 2.1gb but I can't read the resulting file. I will retry

Comment: @sw. Try again, preferrably on a fast connection. Dropbox sometimes just stops transferring, leaving you with an incomplete file.

Comment: This will not work with folders > 1GB or with more than 10,000 files:  https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/49

Comment: to those that said it didn't work, check that the url doesn't already have ?dl=0 embedded in it somewhere. If it does then change this to ?dl=1 and it should work (given above caveats on number of files and folder size) [just worked for me Feb '18]

Comment: I managed to download the folder as a zip file (I used the technique described by likeitlikeit) but I can't open it. I get the message "the compressed folder is invalid". Any idea why is it so?

Comment: If it doesn't work, make sure, that the file was not "Person X wants to share with you Y". This does not work.

Answer (score 14):

As of the moment the following is possible: Go to your shared folders overview, select the folder you want to download -> a context menu appears at the top of the list with a download button. This downloads the whole folder as a zip.

[image: Download Dropbox]

Comment: Yup, going up one level to the top of my Dropbox did it. Select (or right-click) the folder and there's a download link indeed.

Comment: For large folders it is necessary to download subfolders separately. At least at free account.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot download the entire folder without adding it to your Dropbox first.

Since you said the folder is too large for your Dropbox, you will need to download every individual item separately like you would download any other file from the Internet (right-click the item, then Save Link/Target As...).

Answer (score 2):

Go to the `Files` tab of the website interface, right click on the folder, and select `Download`:

[image: Screenshot of download process]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to append the `?dl=1` to an invite link someone sent me but it didn't work.

But this worked for me:

- Go to parent folder of the shared folder (for me it was `dropbox.com/home`)
- Hover over the shared folder row
- On the right is a drop down labeled "Share"
- Click Share button, Click "Send Link" menu item
- Pop up window shows link to share
- Link is of the following format: `https://www.dropbox.com/sh/scramble-01/scramble-02?dl=0`
- Using the technique as described by @likeitlikeit
- Change to: `https://www.dropbox.com/sh/scramble-01/scramble-02?dl=1`

Answer (score -1):

You can use the download manager JDownloader. 
Just copy the link to the clipboard and this app will individually find and list all the files and folders on their LinkGrabber tab. Select all them and hit start.

It's not necessary to have a Dropbox account for this.

http://jdownloader.org/

Answer (score -2):

Right click the folder and press 'Download'… it's as easy as that!

Comment: Adding a screenshot would make your question not just a oneliner

Answer (score -2):

The easiest way is to download the PC application and then the application downloads all the contents in your PC, then you can cut the files and paste in a hard disk or anything you want, and your dropbox space will be empty again.

Comment: OP said they don't have enough space to add it their own Dropbox account, so they won't be able to download it.

Answer (score -2):

The answer that work for me was the one that alex mention above..

1. Share it to yourself
2. Take the link
3. paste it to your browser
4. Then you can download the file.

My file was 3gb.. and i couldnt download it normaly. It was saying that it was too big...! :)

Answer (score -3):

Accept the invitation. Go to Finder on your own computer and your shared folder will be there.

Comment: The OP says the folder is too large to add to her Dropbox.

Answer (score -3):

I created a number of file folders and chopped up the multiple files that were in the "too big to download file" that someone sent me. Then downloaded the 10 folders individually i broke them up into. Of course this won't work if it's just one big file...but if it's photos or elements, you can break it up. This is why I don't use dropbox, too many issues like desktop app not working, etc.

Answer (score -3):

The only thing I can think of to do, is if you can play the file, then do a screen record.  You may need additional software.

Answer (score -3):

Simplest and working solution is to add `raw=0` at the end of the URL.